# Data type conversion issue in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that looks like this from a !cat

```
,City,region,Res_Comm,mkt_type,Quradate,National_exp,Alabama_exp,Sales_exp,Inventory_exp,Price_exp,Credit_exp
0,Dothan,South_Central-Montgomery-Auburn-Wiregrass-Dothan,Residential,Rural,2010-01-15,2,2,3,2,3,3
1,Dothan,South_Central-Montgomery-Auburn-Wiregrass-Dothan,Residential,Suburban_Urban,2010-07-15,2,2,3,2,2,2
2,Dothan,South_Central-Montgomery-Auburn-Wiregrass-Dothan,Residential,Suburban_Urban,2011-01-15,2,2,2,2,2,2
```

When I read it in via a read_csv I get a dataframe all of the ..._exp fields are single digit numbers that I need to do basic math with (It was working great when I was using read-table with another variant of the file)

```
df = pd.io.parsers.read_csv('/home/tom/Dropbox/Projects/annonallanswerswithmaster1012013.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=['Quradate'])
```

But when I go to do any math I get a type error indicating the column is string eg:

```
df['Credit_exp'] = df['Credit_exp']/2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

I don't see how to convert or get it as a int?
I tried specifying field types like ,dtype={'Credit_exp': np.int32, ... in the file read options,, it did not like that 
and I tried to do a type conversion like
df['Credit_exp'] = int(df['Credit_exp'])
Which just gave me:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

So there is something obvious I'm missing...

Comment: Which version of pandas do you use? Your sample is working for me with a 0.12. Otherwise `df['Credit_exp'].apply(int)` could do the trick. NB: your division will be euclidean

Comment: On 12+ dev of Pandas.. so I'll try apply(int) I still don't get why the Dtype={ does not work on read_csv?

Comment: It seems your raw data is not clean. "Credit_exp" column may contain some string values. Try data['Credit_exp'].astype('int') and see what error message you got.

Comment: df['Credit_exp'] = df['Credit_exp'].apply(int) gives me ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\\N'

Comment: @dartdog: that means that one of your `Credit_exp` values *isn't* a single digit, it's what looks like a corrupted endline marker.

Comment: Ok, what's the qick and dirty to remove? (and identify?)

Comment: as @DSM pointed out, a quick way is to drop this value. run df[df['Credit_exp']!='\\N']['Credit_exp'].astype(int). if no error occurs, you're good to go. otherwise, try numpy.unique(df['Credit_exp']) and sense check string values. and of course drop them

Comment: AHH Got it,, 82 out of 8,000 + records bad,,, Thanks! Funny This is a straight MySql dump..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
df.Credit_exp.astype('int')
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html

Comment: df['Credit_exp'] = df.Credit_exp.astype('int')   Gives me ::: ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '\\N'

Comment: It's because the column has data that is not an integer as the exception indicates. It probably is cause of the file formatting